# Is there a tool for expanding XML document templates with XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, templating

I like writing HTML and tend to write flat websites with little JavaScript. I have been noodling around the idea of writing a new "language" of sorts that uses XPath and XMLNS to reference other documents.

I have been playing around with how I would want to write my HTML, which I'd then run a build tool over to expand and build the full document.

Is there a tool that does something like this? I'd rather re-use or learn from a tool that already exists. I suspect I am missing an obvious or common tool that already does something similar.

## Example

This is generally how I'd like to write the HTML (or `HTMPL` as I've been calling it because it's templating).

#### index.htmpl

```
<html xmlns:custom="card.htmpl">
    <custom:card img="/path/to/image.jpg">
        <title>Title content here</title>
        This is the card
    </custom:card>
</html>
```

#### card.htmpl

```
<div class="card">
    <img src="[[//card@img]]" />
    <div class="title">The title is: [[//card/title/text()]]</div>
    <div class="content">[[//card/text()]]</div>
</div>
```

#### Result

*With the extra whitespace removed*

```
<html>
    <div>
        <img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />
        <div class="title">The title is: Title content here</div>
        <div class="content">This is the card</div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: instantly remind me of XSLT...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT was designed to do this job.

XSLT has a concept called "simplified stylesheets" that's designed for cases where what you want is very simple templates, but simplified stylesheets are rarely used because most people find that they end up needing the full language.

Your example could be written in XSLT 3.0 (using simplified stylesheets) like this:

**data.xml**

```
<custom:card img="/path/to/image.jpg">
    <title>Title content here</title>
    This is the card
</custom:card>
```

**template.xsl**

```
<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xsl:version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="{//card/@img}" />
    <div class="title">The title is: {//card/title/text()}</div>
    <div class="content">{//card/text()}</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

But as I say, this way of using XSLT has not proved very popular.

There are other (non-standardized) templating languages available such as Velocity and Freemarker. Take your pick at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines, or design your own if you feel a need to add yet another one to the list.

Comment: XSLT is the tool I thought must exist and serves this purpose. The only thing is it inverts the dependency I am looking for. XSLT seems to use XSL to define the result and query the data for how to inflate itself, while I'm looking for the data to to define the bulk of the layout and have the XSL-equivalent inflate the data.

Unless someone else can provide a tool that perfectly solves my problem, I'll accept your answer as it is likely the closest thing.

Comment: I have added examples of how this would look using XSLT 3.0 simplified stylesheets, to show how similar it is to your proposed syntax.